# Need read some data from JSON

Tags: python, json

I need to make a get (id, name, fraction id) for each deputy in this json

```
{
    "id": "75785",
    "title": "(за основу)",
    "asozdUrl": null,
    "datetime": "2011-12-21T12:20:26+0400",
    "votes": [
        {
            "deputy": {
                "id": "99111772",
                "name": "Абалаков Александр Николаевич",
                "faction": {
                    "id": "72100004",
                    "title": "КПРФ"
                }
            },
            "result": "accept"
        },
        {
            "deputy": {
                "id": "99100491",
                "name": "Абдулатипов Рамазан Гаджимурадович",
                "faction": {
                    "id": "72100024",
                    "title": "ЕР"
                }
            },
            "result": "none"
        }
    .......,`   etc
```

---

My code is looks like that:

```
urlData = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/data-dumaGovRu/vote/master/poll/2011-12-21/75785.json"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(urlData)
content = response.read()
data = json.loads(content.decode("utf8"))
for i in data:    
    #print(data["name"])
```

`
And i dont know what to do with that #print line, how I should write it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the list containing the deputies with `data['votes']`. Iterating through the list, you can access the keys you're interested in as you would with dict key lookups. Nested dicts imply you have to walk through the keys starting from the root to your point of interest:

```
for d in data['votes']:
    print(d['deputy']['id'], d['deputy']['name'], d['deputy']['faction']['id'])
```